# Implementing a global lock in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, global

I have a relatively simple (perhaps stupid) question regarding synchronisation in Java.

I have synchronisation blocks that acquire locks on various objects throughout my code. In some scenarios, I want to acquire a global lock that subsumes every other synchronisation statement in my code.

Is there a fancy way to do this in Java without re-writing all the current synchronisation code?

For example,

### Thread t1

```
synchronized (o1)
{
    synchronized (o2)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

### Thread t2

```
synchronized (global_lock)
{
    // ...
}
```

When thread t2 is inside the synchronised block, thread t1 should not be allowed to acquire the locks on o1 and o2.

Many thanks
if

Comment: a global lock sounds like a really bad idea.....

Comment: You are right, it is a bad idea in general. I need it for what I am implementing unfortunately. I suspect I could use the java.util.concurrent package in some way, but I would need to re-write the synchronised blocks; would rather not do that! :)

Comment: Why do you not want to rewrite the synchronized blocks? If you are afraid that your code will break, then I recommend reading up on concurrency (JCiP is a good book) and taking back control of your code.

Comment: Without going into too much detail, I am using ownership types to infer the necessary locks for particular code blocks. In some cases we are not sure which objects are aliases and hence we need to provide overly conservative locking. To do this correctly, we would need an intra-procedural analysis to determine the points-to set of each variable.

To save time we instead plan to acquire a global lock when it is possible that certain types of owned variables may be aliased within a specific code block.

I was hoping to not have to change the current synchonized code generation because of time :)

Answer (score 11):

1. It's not possible;
2. It's a *really* bad idea ( sorry ).

It's deadlock-prone, since it forces you to have a pre-determined locking order for *all* locks, no matter where they are.

Usually it's a good idea, if you need to acquire two locks, to always have a predetermined order:

```
synchronized(LOCK1) {
  synchronized(LOCK2) {

  }
}
```

But a global lock would need some sort of protocol - a global aquisition order - for all the locks. And that may not be possible at all. Most locks guard specific, self-contained, critical sections. They would be unaware that someone would 'yank' them out and aquire them and therefore would not be written to handle this situation.

So it's not possible, and you should be happy it's not. Although it seems to be the easy way out, it would bring *a lot* of pain.

Comment: Wow can't believe this question was asked that long time ago. Global locking is one of the most fundamental needs in the CEP (complex event processing). Commercial products like tibco businessevents have built-in support of such. And yes, when you need to obtain multiple locks, sorting them in the same order is a must. I came to this question because I need to similar things using a generic approach, without special/commercial tooling support.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the sheer horror of what you are proposing, you may want to consider using Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) to "weave" additional synchronization/locking into your code at run time. You should be able to do this without writing the source.

There are many AOP options, including AspectJ and Spring AOP, which may be suitable depending on your environment.

Answer (score -1):

The only feasible way to do it would be actually parse/modify/save (automatically) all the code. I did something like this for a project recently and it worked pretty good. We can talk more if you are interested.